# Positioning item in page from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show item of a page from bottom to top. Like in chatting or messaging last item is showed in bottom then rest followed to top. Here is an example:

```css
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
  <div class="chart">
        <div style="height: 10px; width: 100%; ">
          10</div>
        <div style="height: 15px; width: 100%; ">
            15</div>
        <div style="height: 20px; width: 100%; ">
            20</div>
        <div style="height: 25px; width: 100%; ">
            25</div>
        <div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; ">
            30</div>
   </div>
```

Here I want, it will show from 10 to 30 bottom to top anything to do with CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This can be VERY easily achieved with CSS flexbox. You may have to add some vendor prefixes, but essential it is done with these 2 lines of code to the parent `.chart` (You also need to add `width: 100%` to the children)

CSS:

```
.chart  { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
}
.chart div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the items show in reverse. Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxtqfqw9/5/

If you want to learn more about the awesome power of flexbox, and how to harness it, I wrote an article that has 2 very helpful resources. :)

http://www.joshuasanger.ca/so-long-floats/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `jquery` like below. First take all div in `.chart` as array and then reverse the array. After that replace the contents of `.chart` with the array.

```js
var item = $('.chart div').toArray().reverse();
$('.chart').html(item);
```

```css
.chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
    <div style="height: 10px; width: 100%; ">
        10
    </div>
    <div style="height: 15px; width: 100%; ">
        15
    </div>
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 100%; ">
        20
    </div>
    <div style="height: 25px; width: 100%; ">
        25
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; ">
        30
    </div>
</div>
```